# Exact algorithms in data structures and graph theory

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, graph

In data structures and algorithms, what is meant by "Exact Graph Algorithms"? Can you give me some examples?

Answer (score 2):

I suppose it refers to whether the algorithm yields a result, that is optimal for a given problem or if it yields "just" an approximative result.

For example, if you are looking in a graph for the [shortest path](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest_path) from one node to another, there are a bunch of algorithms ([Dijkstra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm), [Floyd-Warshall](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd%E2%80%93Warshall_algorithm),... you name them) that solve the problem exactly, i.e. they yield a shortest path between the two given nodes.

On the other hand, consider the [Travelling Salesman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem) problem. It states the question of a shortest circular path containing some given nodes. This problem is [NP-complete](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-complete), and thus (supposedly) not solvable exactly in a reasonable amount of time (at least for the general case). However, there exist approximation algorithms running in reasonable amount of time, that yield a solution that is at most `2*length(best route)` (at least for metric TSP), so the solution from this algorithm is not an exact one, but just an approximation.

Comment: Travelling Salesman Problem has fast 'approximation within twice optimal' algorithms only for special cases like the Euclidean version. For general graphs, there is no polynomial time algorithm (unless P=NP) which can find approximate tour to within constant factor of optimal.

Comment: The twice optimal construction requires only the very reasonable restriction that the distances are symmetry and satisfy the triangle inequality.  (In other words that the distances satisfy axioms of a metric space.)  If the distances can be just anything, then asking for a solution within a constant factor of optimal is hardly different from asking for an optimal solution.